# Delphi. Как изменить поведение ComboBox?

Tags: delphi, combobox

**Здравствуйте!**

Не могу добиться следующего поведения Combobox, список которого загружается автоматически из базы данных, по первым буквам в Combobox.

**Задача:**

1. Набрать часть поисковой строки и нажать Enter
   2  список автоматом заполняется из БД по запросу, удовлетворяющей частичному слову.
2. Открывается список, оператор выбирает из списка нужную строку.

```
procedure TForm29.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    var i: integer;
    begin
      if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
      begin
          ComboBox1.DroppedDown:=FALSE;
          ComboBox1.AutoCloseUp:=FALSE;
    
          FDQuery1.Close;
          FDQuery1.ParamByName('fam').AsString:= ComboBox1.Text;
          FDQuery1.Prepare;
          FDQuery1.Open;
          ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
          while not FDQuery1.Eof do begin
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(FDQuery1.Fields.Fields[0].AsString);
            FDQuery1.Next;
          end;
          FDQuery1.Close;
          Combobox1.SetFocus;
          ComboBox1.DroppedDown:=TRUE;
          //SendMessage(ComboBox1.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, WPARAM(true), 0);
    
      end;
    
    end;
```

Сейчас при выполнении первых двух условий, выбирается самый первый по списку и закрывается список.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

у вас пробелма из за того что вы не правильное событие выбрали, после выполнения вашего кода контрол комбобока получает еще и ентер ( он никуда не делся)

перенесите в **ComboBox1KeyUp** а список разворачивайте с помощью

**combobox1.DroppedDown:=true;**
или если нужно использовать именно ваше событие то обнуляйте нажатую кнопку **key:=#0;** и тогда к самому контролу событие ентера не придет